# Equivalent functionality of `this` and `ref` in c#

Tags: c#, .net, this

If I have a function within a class:

```
/* class snipped */
private void Expect(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, JsonTokenType t)
{
    reader.Read();
    /* snip */
}
```

Which is passed by reference since the object is being manipulated, is this any different to a static helper function:

```
/*static class snipped*/
static public void Expect(this Utf8JsonReader reader, JsonTokenType t)
{
    reader.Read();
    /* snip */
}

// call helper via reader.Expect(requiredToken)
```

I ask in the event of any unseen nuances when `ref` is used, it is heavily in the code alongside `Utf8JsonReader` and `Memory<T>` objects passed down between nested functions.

I am looking to refactor (and would be far nicer using extension methods on the reader object in this case).

Are `this` (extension method on external class) and `ref` (pass by reference between functions) functionally equivalent?

**Update - `ref this` required??**

As an update, simply using `this` did not work, within `ExpectNamedProperty` function it would call `reader.Expect` but on returning the object would revert. Somehow a copy is being made on the stack or something is going on.

I didnt even know this was a valid combination, `ref this` does work, whereas `this` only does not modify. Need to clarify not doing something terrible!

```
public static void Expect(ref this Utf8JsonReader reader, JsonTokenType t)
{
    reader.Read(); // this mutation is never passed back to caller      
}

public static void ExpectNamedProperty(ref this Utf8JsonReader reader, string expectedPropertyName)
{
    reader.Expect(JsonTokenType.PropertyName, expectedPropertyName);

    // at this point it is as if the function above was never called

    var foundPropertyName = reader.GetString();

    if (foundPropertyName != StreamFieldNames.Event)
        throw new JsonException($"expected {StreamFieldNames.Event} found {foundPropertyName} at position {reader.Position.GetInteger()}");
}
```

Comment: `this` makes `Expect` being an *extension method* for `Utf8JsonReader`: you can put `reader.Expect(t);` then.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but do you even need `ref` in your first example? Wouldn't that really only be needed if you intended to change the reference of the `reader` itself? (i.e. reader = <some other Utf8JsonReader>)

Comment: @CodeStranger It's a struct, if he uses the `System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader` I would write it as `private void Expect(in Utf8JsonReader reader, in JsonTokenType t)` which gives the same the readonly advances over `ref`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen - Thanks! Never used that before. Wrong of me to assume I guess.

Comment: @CodeStranger I thought it would be a class, same here.. I had to look it up first, never used it

Comment: What would be the purpose of `Expect` while making it an extension method?

Comment: My first reaction was "What genius decided this should be a struct rather than implementing TextReader!?".  But I see it's intended to work more than Memory/Span/etc

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn yep.  It has an field of type `ReadOnlySpan<T>` which is a ref struct.  And only a ref scruct can have another ref struct as a field.   Else `Field or auto-implemented property cannot be of type 'ReadOnlySpan<byte>' unless it is an instance member of a ref struct.`  JSON parsing is so foundational these days, that a lot of performance engineering went into the design of that type.  Kind of like the way XmlSerializer generated dynamic serialization assemblies back in its day.

Comment: Why would you ever want to use `ref this`?  As others have mentioned, `this` makes it an extension method. Marking it as `ref` allows you to change the object pointed to, which is a massive violation of the [principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment) for an extension method.

Comment: @Powerlord fair point... partial class was the solution in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ref` is fine. And `ref this` is equivalent to / another form of

> ExtensionsClass.ExpectNamedProperty(ref reader)

#### Meanwhile, **DO NOT USE `in`**.

`in` makes performance worse in this case.

`in` works perfectly for `readonly struct`, whereas for non-readonly struct, the compiler creates defensive copy **every time** the struct is used to make sure the struct is readonly. This significantly degrades performance.

In your case, [`Utf8JsonReader`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs) is a `ref struct`, not `readonly struct`.

Consider this example:

```
private void ExpectWithIn(in Utf8JsonReader reader)
{
    reader.Read();
}

private void ExpectWithRef(ref Utf8JsonReader reader)
{
    reader.Read();
}

ExpectWithRef(ref reader);
ExpectWithIn(reader);
```

The compiled IL of `ExpectWithRef`:

```
// (no C# code)
IL_0000: nop
// reader.Read();
IL_0001: ldarg.1
IL_0002: call instance bool [System.Text.Json]System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader::Read()
IL_0007: pop
// (no C# code)
IL_0008: ret
```

The compiled IL of `ExpectWithIn`:

```
// (no C# code)
IL_0000: nop

// The compiler creates defensive copy to make sure reader variable is readonly
// The compiler repeats this for every use of reader variable
// so this is significant impact 

// Utf8JsonReader utf8JsonReader = reader;
IL_0001: ldarg.1
IL_0002: ldobj [System.Text.Json]System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader
IL_0007: stloc.0


// utf8JsonReader.Read();
IL_0008: ldloca.s 0
IL_000a: call instance bool [System.Text.Json]System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader::Read()
IL_000f: pop
// (no C# code)
IL_0010: ret
```

Sergey Tepliakov has [a good article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/the-in-modifier-and-the-readonly-structs-in-c/) explaining the `in` modifier and when to use it.

> It means that you should never pass a non-readonly struct as in parameter. It almost **always will make the performance worse**.

Comment: So the whole `in` keyword is nothing more than a pseudo solution, instead of a solid "do not create a copy" and pass by a reference.only readonly. It doesn't not give any improvement over a normal argument.

Comment: I've did some tests on sharplab, I see the defensive copy when a method is called. Only when the fields are accessed, the copy isn't made.

Answer (score 4):

You could write many extension methods, but are they really related? Writing every thing in extension methods will generate spaghetti code.

I would go for the `in` keyword. The advances of `in` over `ref` is that you are not able te modify the parameter, but you won't get a copy (like a "normal" parameter). Also you can pass readonly fields as `in` parameter.

```
private void Expect(in Utf8JsonReader reader, in JsonTokenType t)
{
   reader.Read();
    /* snip */
}
```

Comment: And you can do both `Expect(this in Utf8JsonReader reader, JsonTokenType t)`

Comment: Like I said, is it really close related to the Utf8JsonReader? Is it used on many spots in de the code? A problem with using it as an extension method, is that this no longer supports inheritance. You're not able to override it.

Comment: Yes appreciate that point. There are lots of Expects that are slightly different, and they take up the majority of the class. By putting them in an extension method would make actual class using the extensions a lot clearer in this case.

Comment: `in` cannot be used on `Utf8JsonReader`. I post an answer to explain why.

Comment: In this case partial class was relevant, as using the ref and this together required was modifying the item (which was required) but would not have been clear to any other developer hence dangerous. Partial class at least made it explicitly clear